# Category post count is not correct

Tags: categories, loop, taxonomy, blog

When I go to Posts > Categories, some categories show that they have a post. See screenshot. But there are no posts linked to that category. When you click on that "1"-number, no posts are shown.

[image: post categories]

This is an issue because my blog page shows the category title and description even if there are no actual posts linked to that category (Wedge-system - see screenshot).

This is how I loop over all the categories and show the posts from that category:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type' => 'Post',
                            'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                    'field'    => 'id',
                                    'terms'    => array( $category->term_id ),
                                    'operator' => 'IN'
                                ),
                            ),
                        )
                        );
?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    /* post template here */
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: That post count number encompasses _all_ post types using that term, not just the post type you're using to access that list in the admin. So if you don't have a `post` with that term, you have some other post type with that term, hence the `1`. Yes, it is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You're a post type that doesn't exist, there is no `Post` post type, did you mean `post`?

---

Sidenotes:

- `wp_reset_query` is only for use after `query_posts` you should be using `wp_reset_postdata` instead.
- There is no `if ( $loop->have_posts() )` check so if no posts are found there is no message and it looks like the page is broken
- This page would be much faster if you used category archives for your category archives, then used `pre_get_posts` to modify the query, instead of a page template and a brand new custom query

  - if you are doing this on `category.php` or `archive.php` then you're doubling the number of queries so that you can change `posts_per_page`, use `pre_get_posts` to change it instead